# Setting the Axis origin in the MSChart control

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vb6, mschart

I'm putting together a graph with the MSChart control for VB6.  Is there a way to adjust the location of the points on the X axis so that the first data point in the series sits against the Y axis?  By default it floats in a space between the origin and the first gridline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to see questions left unanswered, so here's my solution to the problem at the time.

If you use a large number of data points in the grid, the first point still won't really sit next to hte Y axis; however, if the graph is scaled correctly, it does look like it, and you won't be able to tell the difference.  Turns out the problem is only visible with a small number of data points in the series.

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting :

```
chartArea.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```